# How to replace implementation to compile in Android Build.gradle. (Android Studio 2.3.3)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing an app of barcode scanner.

URL : [Barcode Scanner URL Here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6095)

My Android Studio version is 2.3.3

I always used compile in build.gradle (module:app) but i found this library suggested to use **implementation** in replace of **compile**.

I searched over internet **compile** is replaced by **implementation**  in Android studio 3.0 but i have to use this library in Android studio 2.3.3.

**example.**

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:1.5.7'
}
```

when I put this in my gradle its showing error.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:1.5.7' // HERE
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Error is:**

```
    Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
    Install Repository and sync project
    Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Please tell me how can i use this library in my android studio 2.3.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add **Google's Maven repository** in your top-level **`build.gradle`** .

```
      allprojects {
      repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, nothing happens same error message . I added in build.gradle compile 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:1.5.7' , I replaced implementation to compile.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar As per https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner you should use `implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:1.5.7'` .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya right

Comment: But my Android studio is 2.3.3, i am not able to resolve error .

Comment: @Abhishekkumar use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'`

Comment: @Abhishekkumar Kindly review here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: where i have to add this ?classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'

Comment: @Abhishekkumar solved this yet ?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Amiya  If i am using Android Studio 3 Its working fine but in Android Studio 2.3.3 still getting error.

Answer (score 1):

Add Maven repo to your project level gradle like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

       maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

This is for Android Studio version `2.3.3` or Gradle version lower than `4.1`

Comment: i added but same error message coming.

Comment: What is your buildToolsVersion?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'